# Bootstrap Checkbox Others with textfield

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm new to bootstrap but so far nothing comes up when i search for bootstrap checkboxes that need a custom field for "others". I'm using a horizontal form-control so width will be 100% which I need for mobile use.

Please take a look at the property type checkbox. I need an others field that must be full width of the column.

I've tried

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="propertytype-8">
        <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype" id="propertytype-8" value="others">
    </label>
        <input id="propertytype_other" name="propertytype_other" type="text" value=""     placeholder="other" class="form-control">
</div>
```

which results in

[image]

and

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="propertytype-8">
        <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype" id="propertytype-8" value="others">
        <input id="propertytype_other" name="propertytype_other" type="text" value=""     placeholder="other" class="form-control">
    </label>
</div>
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: Is it that you want the text field to be full width and beside the checkbox?

Comment: Do you actually need a checkbox for other?

Comment: Yes Jasper, i want it beside the checkbox but also full width.

Comment: Hebron, i was thinking of just creating another line for Others, but this is not the only instance where there will be customized others. If you could see in the picture under bedroom, there are currently 4 entries, I will be adding an other field as well for a number of bedroom a person wishes to enter. I do not want to have to add a 4BR, 5BR, and a checkbox that states "Others, please provide more info in the other details textarea"

Comment: My last option will be to provide a checkbox for others and will use javascript to toggle a textfield in the next line. I do not like it this way since it is an extra step for my users. (2 clicks instead of 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add size tag

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="propertytype-8">
       <input type="checkbox" name="propertytype" id="propertytype-8" value="others">
       <input id="propertytype_other" name="propertytype_other" type="text" value="" placeholder="other" class="form-control" size="1000%">      
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I wasn't expecting such a simple solution :)
Btw for other's reading this, I changed to size="100%" and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
            <label class="form-check-label " for="defaultCheck1"> Default checkbox </label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-50" type="text" placeholder=".form-control-sm" style="display: inline">
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2" disabled>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2"> Disabled checkbox </label>
        </div>
    
</div>
```